# Why does Work Done Appear to be More than 100% Energy in a System?

Tags: energy, work, power

Energy is equivalent to the work done on a motor. The work done on the motor is multiplied by more than 100% by *recycling* the *energy* the motor uses. Why then does the energy in the system appear to be more than one hundred percent?

For instance if a motor is powered from a capacitor with 1 joule of energy in it then the motor has done 1 joule's worth of work.

Yet when the *energy is recycled*, by pulsing and recovering the energy through the utilization of a collapsing magnetic field, then the motor can now do more work than what it originally could have done if the energy was used only once.

If the *work done* in the motor is directly related, proportional and equal to the *energy* that was in the capacitor, then would this mean that the energy has now gone above 100% as well? **That is the question**.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated. I will remain neutral to any and all answers as I don't consider them right or wrong.

More information and clarification can be found [here](https://eternalmotor.blogspot.com/2017/07/does-motor-really-consume-energy.html). I actually figured out the answer for myself and hopefully for others as well [here](http://eternalmotor.blogspot.com/2017/08/power-amplification-solved.html).

Comment: -1. Unclear. What exactly is your difficulty? All you seem to be asking is whether it is "safe to say" that 1 Watt-second is the same as 1 Joule, without explaining why you think this *might not* be true.

Comment: I have edited my original question to go along with this comment.  I am asking this question because of the consequences of reusing or recycling energy in order to perform more work than what would normally be done if the energy is used only once. Still unclear? If so just ask I will try to clear it up even more. Please undo the vote down, it's an honest and valid question.

Comment: " but please make sure to stay focused on the original question"  It's very simple. Work transfers energy from one system to another. I don't understand your rambling around this fact.

Comment: What do you not understand about my ramblings? Huh? Do you not read or what? I am saying that you can get more work out of a system by reusing energy repeatedly, therefore get more work than what you normally would if you use the energy just one time, like the motor draining the capacitor away example I set forth. If the work done is equivalent to energy then that would imply that more than 100% energy in a system, if the energy is reused, which we all know is impossible, so you see the merit of the question yet?

Comment: There's no need to take offense and be angry here. Your original question was not very clear and it doesn't look like the addition of ~2000 characters did anything to help the case. As it's written now, it looks like you're asking if energy $\to$ work $\to$ energy $\to$ work increases the energy of the system, which (to many of us) seems a trivial no.

Comment: I wasn't aware of being angry, but I was a bit frustrated, it's somewhat of a difficult question to ask. I've reworded the question, I shaved a ton off, Im not quite so sure why I wasn't able to find the correct way to formulate the words to the questions, I think because in my mind it's somewhat of a paradox as it took me a long time to arrive to that question. I apologize for any inconveniences.

Comment: How can you reuse the energy? If you're storing some unused portion of the original energy, then it wasn't all used in the first place.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. First of all energy can be reused through the motor's magnetic field when it collapses during it's switching off time, which is part of the motoring process. It is possible to use the energy and simultaneously store it. Just think of a gallon of water being poured over a paddle wheel, and then collecting the water in another empty gallon. There we have done work and reused all the energy simultaneously in the water and paddle wheel example.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck In that example you haven't gotten any of the energy back.  The energy you got from the water has nothing to do with collecting the water, and _everything_ to do with it's potential energy due to height.  To get more energy out of the wheel, you would need to raise the water back up, taking just as much (or realistically) more work than you get _from_ the paddle wheel.  I still don't understand the motor system you are talking about (this could really use a diagram instead of a link to a blog with even more words); but I believe a similar logic would apply here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I made a point of relating height to potential or voltage. I will check and make sure though. The water example is just that, an example to relate to electromagnetism. I will revise what I find wrong. I do relate gravity causing the water to fall and then having to go back up against gravity in order to repeat the cycle. I actually have a diagram but forgot to add it, I will add it along with a better diagram I have in mind. Thank you for considering the question. Actually I have a diagram in the one and only other article I have, you just gotta look around a little bit.

Comment: This still isn't very clear.  You need to provide something that shows what you mean by "recycling energy" through a motor.  I suspect it may be more of a case where you are running a motor with "no load" and then using a circuit to reclaim that energy.  In those scenarios the motor can't both do work and repower the circuit.  Making people follow a chain of links to get to the relevant information will likely result in the question not being reopened (especially where the blog seems to be discussing perpetual motion machines, which does not help the case).

Comment: Hi, it's really easy actually. By "recycling energy" I mean taking a simple pulse motor, and pulsing current through it's winding of it's coil. When current is pulsed into the coil a magnetic field is formed of course around the coil. This is stored energy. This is a basic electromagnet. When power is shut off, then the magnetic field collapses and returns back a portion of power. Well known in physics. AKA the kickback spike or fly back voltage. How have I made that unclear? I am not talking about perpetual motion, I am just asking a question pertaining to energy and power.

Comment: Of course the motor can do work and repower the circuit. What I am trying to convey is that the motor uses the power or energy once. If pulsed the energy or power is stored in it's magnetic field repeatedly. So of course the magnetic field collapses repeatedly so the motor can reuse it and become repowered with the recycled energy. Refer back to the main question please. It's a question, it needs an answer. Why can't anybody answer a question? I can't make a question that contains an entire essay. I suppose this is a no win situation.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck That _doesn't_ really do any work besides internally on the motor (minus heating/sound losses).  If the motor were connected to something that it did work on, you would not be getting net energy back in the coil.  Also, what is a "collapsing magnetic field"?

Comment: Well I figured that since the motor is running and being powered does indeed represent real work being done, (your work internally), (minus heating/sound losses and other frictions such as bearing losses, air, gravity, etc.) The system is basic and doesn't matter if it's connected to something that it does work on. The motor itself is working. The collapsing magnetic field is a magnetic field that collapses. The magnetic field must expand first, which is a result of current in the coiled up wire. Disconnecting power or shutting power off results in the magnetic field collapsing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63046/discussion-between-marc-striebeck-and-jmac).

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you can ignore the difference between energy and work.  They're not quite the same, but they're similar enough that, in my experience, I haven't seen anyone get a wrong answer because they got them confused.

[Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) *specifically* is what a force does when there is a displacement in the point of application of that work.   In laymans terms, work is what happens when a force moves something.  By the Work-Energy principle, the amount of kinetic energy gained by a rigid body is exactly equal to the amount of work done on it.

So by that *technical* definition, using a capacitor to power a motor which moves an object is doing work, while using a capacitor to power a lightbulb is not because no kinetic energy was added to any object.  Instead, that electrical potential energy was converted to thermal energy, which was then radiated as light.  In practice, this distinction is not emphasized.  In all situations I am aware of (except perhaps exam questions), I could say "the capacitor is doing work, lighting the light bulb," and people would properly interpret what I meant.

The big difference is really that energy is a property of a "thing" while work is a property of a force.  This is funny since forces aren't "things," but rather abstract mathematical constructs to make sense of how the world works.  Philosophers may squabble over this, but I've never found any practical issue caused by the misuse of work vs. energy.  People generally use the correct word in the correct places.

So, to answer your final question, the only reason 1W of work done over 1 second is not *quite* equivalent to 1J of energy is simply because work is associated with a force, while energy is associated with a thing.  However, practically speaking, I've never seen any reason why you would get in trouble thinking of them as equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. The long answer is somewhat more subtle. It is true that work is dimensionally equivalent to energy (their units are the same). Therefore, you could always say that work represents energy.

The subtility lies in the fact that there are different forms of energy. If I lift a stone of $0.1$ g $1$ m above the ground, it will have gained approximately $1$ Joule of energy (the gravitational potential energy is $mgh$, with $m$ the mass, $g$ the earth's gravity field ($9.81 m /s^2$), and $h$ the height). However, due to air friction, I will have performed slightly more work than that (although the difference would be negligible). Also, my body will have used more energy than the amount of work I did, because the human body definitely does not have a $100 \%$ efficency when converting energy into this kind of work. Where, then, did the excess energy go?

The answer is heat. Heat is also a form of energy. Whenever something moves in a non-ideal environment, it will undergo friction, and that friction will cause some energy to dissipate as heat.

To summarize, in an ideal situation, you can generally say that work done equals change in energy. In a non-ideal situation, this is also true, but some of the energy will be dissipated as heat.

Comment: Hi, those are both good enough answers for me. I probably should not have included a light bulb as a load, although yes in an ideal situation, if there is such a thing, the energy is wasted away as heat waste. As with the motor we can at least see what's going in, but it also has losses such as frictions of all sorts, lenz's law and too many really to mention right here and right now.

Comment: Heat is a *transfer* of energy due to temperature differences. The temperature increase of an object due to friction is a mechanical process, not heat in the proper physics definition. And objects do not contain heat. When you rub your hands together rapidly, the increase in temperature is due to part of kinetic energy of the hands and arms being transferred (by work) into the molecular structure, increasing the KE of those molecules. The internal energy increases. The hands will then emit heat (energy transferred) because they are warmer than the surroundings.